# Webpack code spiltting + vue + Dynamic css loading

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-router

Following code-splitting recommendations from [Webpack](https://alexjoverm.github.io/2017/07/16/Lazy-load-in-Vue-using-Webpack-s-code-splitting/) and [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html), I am lazy loading heavy pages in my routes using dynamic import as such:

```
const Login = () => import("../views/Login/Login.vue");
```

However if this login.vue page contains an import statement for a css, the style is not properly loaded.

```
<script>
import '@/assets/sass/my_login.scss'
...
```

If I remove the dynamic import of the Login.vue page in my routes such as

```
import Login from '../views/Login/Login.vue'
```

The css is correctly loaded.

I want to load this Vue page asyncly by using dynamic import and I don't want to make this css global as it is only needed by this specific page.

How am I loading properly this css? Is there some magic syntax to be used in the Login.vue page or in the routes?

Thank your for your help

S.

Comment: Are you using any project templates, or did you create your own project's webpack config?

Comment: I use a template based on the latest vue-cli

Comment: Then why don't you use the vue single file component script tag, instead of trying to import it separately? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want global styles, you can write scope styles in your components.
Have u tried this?

```
<style scoped>
```

(in your *.vue files)